# prove that f(t) is an even function

Tags: functions

If $f(t)={{t}\over{e^t-1}}+{t\over{2}}+1$ , prove that $f(t)$ is an even function.

So i proceeded the usual way by substituting $-t$ in $f(t)$

$f(-t)={{-t}\over{e^{-t}}-1}-{{t}\over{2}}+1$

$={{-te^t}\over{1}-e^t}-{{t}\over{2}}+1$

which on further simplifying gives:-
$f(-t)={{-te^{-t}-t+2}\over{2}}$

since this is not equal to $f(t)$ i now i went wrong somewhere so can someone please point out  the mistake or  if i need to take a different approach.

Comment: Prove that $f(t) - f(-t)=0$

Comment: See : $f(t) - f(-t) = \dfrac{t}{e^t-1}+\dfrac{t}{2}+1 - \dfrac{t e^t}{e^t-1}+\dfrac{t}{2}-1$, then you have : $f(t) - f(-t) = \dfrac{t(1-e^t)}{e^t-1} + t = -t+t=0$

Answer (score 2):

$$f(t)=t\left(\frac{e^t+1}{2(e^t-1)}\right)+1$$

$$f(-t)=-t\left(\frac{e^{-t}+1}{2(e^{-t}-1)}\right)+1=-t\left(\frac{1+e^t}{2(1-e^t)}\right)+1=f(t)$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\dfrac{-te^t}{1-e^t}=\dfrac{t(e^t-1+1)}{e^t-1}=t+\dfrac t{e^t-1}$$  for $e^t-1\ne0$

Answer (score 0):

How did you get from ${{-te^t}\over{1}-e^t}-{{t}\over{2}}+1$ to ${{-te^{-t}-t+2}\over{2}}$?

${{-te^t}\over{1}-e^t} \ne {{-te^t}\over{2}}$

If you do put over a common denominator you get:

$\frac {-2te^t -t(1-e^t) +2(1-e^t)}{2(1-e^t)} =\frac {-te^t -t -2e^t+2}{2-2e^t}$

Meanwhile $f(t) = {{t}\over{e^t-1}}+{t\over{2}}+1 =$

$\frac {2t + t(e^t -1) + 2(e^t -1)}{2(e^t-1)}=\frac{te^t +t+2e^t-1}{2e^2 - 2}$

And it's easy to see that $\frac {-te^t -t -2e^t+2}{2-2e^t} = \frac{te^t +t+2e^t-1}{2e^2 - 2}$.

But perhaps an easier way to keep your thinking toward a goal is to think

${{-t}\over{e^{-t}}-1}-{{t}\over{2}}+1 = {{t}\over{e^{t}}-1}+{{t}\over{2}}+1\iff$

${{-t}\over{e^{-t}}-1}-{{t}\over{e^{t}}-1}= {{t}\over{2}} +{{t}\over{2}} \iff$

$\frac {-te^t}{1-e^t} - \frac t{e^t - 1} = t\iff$

$\frac{te^t}{e^t -1} - \frac t{e^t -1} = t \iff$

$\frac {te^t - t}{e^t - 1} = t \iff$

$\frac {t(e^t -1)}{e^t -1} = t$

Which is true so long as $t\ne 0$ (but $0$ is not in the domain of $f$ so that is always the case).

.....

Perhaps to be more formal and direct:

$f$ is even if $f(t) = f(-t)$ or in other words if $f(t) - f(-t) =0$

So $(\frac {t}{e^t -1} + \frac t2 + 1) - (\frac {-t}{e^{-t} -1} - \frac t2 + 1) = $

$\frac {t}{e^t -1} + \frac {t}{e^{-t} -1} + t=$

$\frac{t}{e^t-1} + \frac {te^t}{1-e^t} + t =$

$\frac {t - te^t + t(e^t - 1)}{e^t - 1} = $

$\frac {t(1-e^t + e^t -1)}{e^t -1}=\frac {t*0}{e^t -1 } = 0$